# Limitar input html

Tags: html, input

Quero colocar um input no html e quero limitar apenas a 2 numeros.

```
<input type="text" name="Dia" maxlength="2" size="2" >
```

Experimentei este mas continua a aparecer letras.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Para limitar o `input` a números basta mudar o *type* de *text* para *number*:

```html
<form action="#">
  <input type="number" name="Dia" min="1" max="31">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Ainda se quiser limitar de 1 a 31 (imaginando que seja o número de dias do mês) pode fazê-lo com `mim` e `max`.

*Nota: Este tipo `number` não funciona no IE9 nem versões anteriores.*

No caso de precisar que funcione em IE9 ou anterior pode usar JavaScript:

```html
<form action="#">
  <input type="text" maxlength="2" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'></input>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

[Fonte do exemplo com `onkeypress`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/469362/1817673)

Comment: Trocando o `type` para `number` não resolve, pois ainda continua aceitando Letras. Alias ele tornará o `input` em um "seletor" de numeros, mas não impedirá de o usuário digitar números.

Comment: Não aceita letras, olha testa @MeuChapeu. Dá `submit` a ver se aceita.

Comment: Correto, ao clicar no `submit` ele irá avisar que aceita somente números, mas não impedirá que o usuário digite as letras. Ao contrário do evento `onkeypress` que só permite digitar números.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o evento `onkeypress`:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="2" onkeypress="if (!isNaN(String.fromCharCode(window.event.keyCode))) return true; else return false;">
```

Toda vez que uma tecla for presiona dentro do `input` o evento será ativado, e verificara se a tecla presiona é ou não um número, caso seja letras retornara `false`, se for número retornará `true` e irá aparecer no `input`.

Veja como ficou no [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/6zn8wwuL/)

***OBS: O evento `onkeypress` não está funcionando no Firefox***

Comment: O `onkeypress` funciona sim no Firefox, o que acontece é que o `window.event` não existe. Uma solução com o mesmo resultado, funcionando também no Firefox é essa: `return !isNaN(event.key);`. Mas essa abordagem tem um problema, pois impede o usuário de interagir no input usando as setas, backspace, delete, etc...

Answer (score -3):

peguei a sugestao do de cima e fiz assim tbm

```
<input id="phone" type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="(xx) xxxxx - xxxx" maxlength="12" onkeypress="if (!isNaN(String.fromCharCode(window.event.keyCode))) return true; else return false;">
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).